# Replacing parameter in URL with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace ":id" in url string with particular id e.g. 54 My question would be is it enough to use "/(:id)/i" for replacing this parameter, or I should use something more complex? Thanks

```js
var url = "http://www.test.com/api/person/:id/details"
var str = url.replace(/(:id)/i, 54);
```

Updated:

I just realized that it would be great to have a function which would be able to replace multiple values in URL. Example:

```
function replaceParametersInUrl(url, params) {
  var regex = new RegExp(Object.keys(params).join('|'), 'gi');
    return url.replace(regex, function(matched) {
    return params[matched];
  });
}

console.log(replaceParametersInUrl("api/person/:userId/items/:itemId",  {userId: 56, itemId: 1}));
```

The problem with this solution is that it replaces just userId and itemId strings without ":". How I can achieve that it would replace those strings including ":"?

Comment: The one you have should be enough. You can also do away with the brackets since in this case you do not need what they provide. Thus `/:id/` would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this function for solving the problem I mentioned in my updated question:

```
function replaceParametersInUrl(url, params) {
  var newObj = {};
  Object.keys(params).forEach(function(key) {
    newObj[':'+key] = params[key];
  });

  var regex = new RegExp(Object.keys(newObj).join('|'), 'gi');
  return url.replace(regex, function(matched) {
    return newObj[matched];
  });
}

console.log(replaceParametersInUrl("api/person/:userId/items/:itemId", {userId: 56, itemId: 1}));
```

Is it ok that I use ":" character in object keys?

Answer (score 1):

In the "normal" case it should be enough. The user could type it `:id` or `:Id` but you already use the incasesensitive flag, so it should be fine.

But you are the one who should know if it is enough. Maybe there is a case in your application where there is an `:id` before the one you want to replace. Than you have a problem with the RegExp given above.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have provided will work fine. Moreover,adding on to your code, braces not neede here `(:id)`. Also, your regex will fail, if there is `:id` anywhere in the URL (although not expected, but developer should take care).
Modified code:

```
var url = "http://www.test.com/api/person/:id/details";
var str = url.replace(/\/:id\//i, '/54/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution I came up with.

```js
const replaceParametersInUrl = (url, params) =>
  url.replace(/:(\w+)/g, (match, group) => {
    if (!params[group]) throw new Error(`Unable to find value for ${match} param`);
    return `${params[group]}`;
  });
```